# Совместимость программ на VB с Windows

Tags: vb6, windows-7

Здравствуйте! Я написал программу на вижуал бейсик и когда запустил ее на другом компьютере где `Windows` 7, там все объекты формы изменили размер - как то съехали и вообще не понятно что получилось! А на другом компьютере все отлично! Где также семерка! Может это какие то настройки `Windows` сбились? Такое даже при одинаковом разрешении экрана происходит... Что еще может повлиять? Могу скинуть скриншот.
Данная проблема возникла на `windows7`!

[image: img]

Answer (score 3):

Причиной проблемы может быть то, что элементы управления в вашей программе имеют жестко заданные размеры, а на другом компьютере при этом установлено иное разрешение экрана, отчего вашим контролам "не хватает места"

Comment: в том то и дело я так и думал!!!где произошел данный сбой разрешение экрана такое 1366х768! но у меня на ноутбуке тоже такое разрешение рабочего стола и я протестировал эту программу на ноуте и все КРУТО!!!!! я попросил того человека поменять разрешение на 1024х768 но все ровно сдвигается так.... причем у меня эта программа при любом разрешении выглядит нормально нечего не сдвигается... дело тут в чем то другом((((

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, дело в настройках dpi. Сравните параметры на двух ноутбуках, которые настраиваются тут: `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display`.

Можно туда добраться через `"Personalization"`, ссылка `"Display"` в `"See also"` слева снизу.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!!! я попробую! надеюсь поможет!!!